# Linux Heartbeat options possibilities

Tags: linux, mysql

I would like to understand if my below scenarios are possible in Heartbeat in Linux.

Setup: Two Database Servers running Mysql in Active/Passive mode in replication mode having Heartbeat setup for HA or failover mechanism. Application connects to DB using VIP that is started at the time of Heartbeat.

- Failover VIP to passive site if primary Mysql intance is shut down.
- Bring down the heartbeat in primary if the role has been given to passive/secondary site inorder to avoid split brain.

Comment: I believe that you need maybe more than just VRRP (Virtual redundant Routing protocol) since DB is involved, This makes me then think that question is more suited to dba.stackexchange.com, than just pure Unix/linux. Here's a [questions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/mysql-high-availability-failover-and-replication-with-latency) that appears to be very closely related. Also probably depends on which engine is used (INNODB, etc). Since failback and recovery should be considered as well.

Comment: Yes I was thinking this Q is probably more suited to either DBA or ServerFault.

Comment: @X Tian: heartbeat normally don't need VRRP it switches the IP's with `ifconfig`.

Comment: @mannoj:  In your case I'd not use heartbeat, but `mysql-ndb`. You'll get then an active/active HA with 2 IP's and a DNS name points to 2 ips so the load balancing is done by a DNS client.

Comment: Pls follow the discussion on http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60216/heartbeat-options-with-mysql-and-possibilities

Comment: @Others - I'm not closing this thread, as this not only deals with Mysql the service could be any. Like drbd, httpd, apache, tomcat etc.. This question is generic to Heartbeat and it is Linux HA. Hence the question stays here too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, this is a very common scenario, and well supported in linux.

Currently the best tool for the job is [Pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/). Pacemaker sits on top of [Corosync](http://corosync.github.io/corosync/) and runs on all the nodes in the cluster. It sends heartbeat messages around, and when it detects that a node has failed, it migrates all resources off that node, and can optionally kill the node (referred to as [fencing](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/crm_fencing.html)).

Resources are things like a VIP, or a MySQL database. Some resources support master/slave modes, in which if the node running the master fails, pacemaker will promote the slave to master.

Resources are driven through scripts, so if it can be scripted, pacemaker can support it. There are a large number of resources already created, so you likely do not need to do this.

It also supports ordering so that when resources are moved around, it can do things like make sure that MySQL has been promoted to master before moving the VIP so that no clients connect to it before it's ready.